# Chrome Web Store payments deprecation - how to migrate

Tags: javascript, php, migration, chrome-web-store, deprecation-warning

On September 21, 2020 The Google Chrome Web Store team sent an email to Chrome Web Store Developers that Chrome web store payments will be shut down very soon. They briefly explained the timeline of shutdowns and what developers that monetize extensions should do, but they did not give any details on how to do it either in the email or the [payments deprecation page](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/cws-payments-deprecation#exporting-user-licenses). Developers, like myself are searching everywhere but not finding answers.

So this is a 3 part question:

1. They say that those using the licensing API should "Prepare a license migration app that runs on your site, which accesses the Chrome Web Store API. This app needs to use OAuth 2.0 to authenticate, with user consent, and fetch the user’s subscription details." How is this done? There were no examples given nor links to documentation. How could this be done using Javascript and PHP?
2. They say that on December 1, 2020 in-app free trials requests will result in an error. What are "in-app free trials requests"?
3. How does a developer find out when a user installed an extension to offer free trial periods? This was done using the licensing API and the createdTime value. But the licensing API is being deprecated.